# Can multiple reinforcement algorithms be applied to the same system?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Can a system, for instance, a robotic vehicle, be controlled by more than one reinforcement learning algorithm. I intend to use one to address collision avoidance whereas the other to tackle autonomous task completion.

Comment: Hi. Maybe you're looking for multi-agent systems or hierarchical reinforcement learning. Have a look at these topics.